# Multidimensional Map

Tags: java, android, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am programming an Android app in university.

The user is asked questions they have to answer.

I get the questions via HTTP request / response from a server. They are delivered as a string. This string looks something like this with 2 questions:

```
(requestedQuestion):

    id: 1
    question: Mit was stylet man HTML?
    answer1: PHP
    answer2: C++
    answer3: Java
    answer4: CSS
    answerR: 4
    picture:
    kind: 4
    category: Webprogrammierung
    semester: 2
    difficulty: 1
    ranking:
    report:
    moderated:
    id: 2
    question: Wie viele Bits hat ein Byte?
    answer1: 4
    answer2: 8
    answer3:
    answer4:
    answerR: 2
    picture:
    kind: 2
    category: Informatik
    semester: 1
    difficulty: 2
    ranking:
    report:
    moderated:
```

I thought to put the string into a multi-dimensional map to better access each attribute.

At the moment we have a simple Map-generator that should generate a normal map but this is not working right:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
  String payload = requestedQuestion;
  String[] keyVals = payload.split("\\s*\n");
  for(String keyVal:keyVals) {
    String[] parts = keyVal.split(":", 2);
    map.put(parts[0],parts[1]);
  }
```

I want to have a multi-dimensional (JSON Response) map like this so we can access each question with its attributes:

```
Map: {question1=
        {
        id= 1,
        question= Mit was stylet man HTML?,
        answer1= PHP,
        answer2= C++,
        answer3= Java,
        answer4= CSS,
        answerR= 4,
        picture=,
        kind= 4,
        category= Webprogrammierung,
        semester= 2,
        difficulty= 1,
        ranking=,
        report=,
        moderated=
        },
      question2=
        {
        id= 2,
        question= Wie viele Bits hat ein Byte?,
        answer1= 4,
        answer2= 8,
        answer3=,
        answer4=,
        answerR= 2,
        picture=,
        kind= 2,
        category= Informatik,
        semester= 1,
        difficulty= 2,
        ranking=,
        report=,
        moderated=
        }
     }
```

Comment: Your Json response are valid?

Answer (score 1):

It's more natural to provide `JSON` answer from the server:

```
{ 
    "id": 1,
    "question": "Mit was stylet man HTML?",
    "answers" : [ 
        { "value": "PHP" },
        { "value" : "C++"}, 
        { "value" : "Java"},
        { "value" : "CSS"}
    ],
    "rightAnswer": 4,
    "kind": 4,
    "category": "Webprogrammierung",
    "semester": 2,
    "difficulty": 1
}
```

For more information about `JSON`, you can look at this [link](http://json.org/)

Then in `Android` you can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or some other library to parse `JSON` responses.

You need to create POJO object and map them with `GSON` annotations. This is examples of `Objects` for `JSON` whic I've provide earlier:

Question:

```
public class Question {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("question")
    @Expose
    private String question;
    @SerializedName("answers")
    @Expose
    private List<Answer> answers = null;
    @SerializedName("rightAnswer")
    @Expose
    private Integer rightAnswer;
    @SerializedName("kind")
    @Expose
    private Integer kind;
    @SerializedName("category")
    @Expose
    private String category;
    @SerializedName("semester")
    @Expose
    private Integer semester;
    @SerializedName("difficulty")
    @Expose
    private Integer difficulty;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public Integer getRightAnswer() {
        return rightAnswer;
    }

    public void setRightAnswer(Integer rightAnswer) {
        this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    }

    public Integer getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(Integer kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Integer getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }

    public void setSemester(Integer semester) {
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    public Integer getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(Integer difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }
}
```

Answer:

```
    public class Answer {

    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

And let us suppose that you get your response in `String` format and store it in `response` variable

```
String response; // store here response of your server request
```

Then simply use `GSON` to parse that `String`:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Qustion question = gson.fromJson(response, Question.class);
```

Now you have `Question` object. You can access fields in a next way

```
List<Answer> answers = quesion.getAnswers();
```

Comment: Thats nice! But how to handle this with multiple questions? How can i intent multiple questions to another Activity in Android?